# Unable to resolve module "../Utilities/Platform"

Tags: react-native, webpack, expo

I trying to run expo-cli in browser mode.

But there is the error:

> Unable to resolve "../Utilities/Platform" from "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactPrivate\ReactNativePrivateInterface.js"

Another question recommended generating the webpack.config.js file from expo. The code in this file is:

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);
  config.resolve.alias['../Utilities/Platform'] =
    'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform'
  return config;
};
```